# How to trigger an event that fires after record in the database is updated? [OctoberCMS]

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-backend

I have been trying to fire an event which tells me if a particular information in the record was changed, however my fails to execute (gives no error as such but doesnt Log the info I expect)

I have added this in the Plugin.php file in the boot function

```
        $comment =  new ExpertsComment;
        $comment->bindEvent('model.afterUpdate', function () use (\October\Rain\Database\Model $model) {
            if ($model->is_approved !== $model->original['is_approved']) {
              Log::info("Event Fired!");
         }
        });
```

used this from here https://octobercms.com/docs/api/model/afterupdate

Answer (score 1):

Is ExpertsComment your class? If so, you can add the event directly to your model in `plugins/foo/bar/models/ExpertsComment.php`. Don't forget to add the Log Facade, `use Log;` in the `ExpertsComment.php`. [Here are documents for model event basic usage.](https://octobercms.com/docs/database/model#basic-usage)

```
public function afterUpdate() 
{
    if ($this->is_approved !== $this->original['is_approved']) {
        Log::info("Event Fired!");
    }
}
```

Or, if you want to extend another class, you can do it in one of your Plugin classes, ie: `plugins/foo/bar/Plugin.php`. [Here are the documents for extending a class.](https://octobercms.com/docs/database/model#extending-models)

```
use Foo\Bar\Models\ExpertsComment;

class Plugin extends PluginBase
{
    ....

    public function boot()
    {
        ExpertsComment::extend(function($model) {
            $model->bindEvent('model.afterUpdate', function() use ($model) {
                if ($model->is_approved !== $model->original['is_approved']) {
                    Log::info("Event Fired!");
                }
            });
        });
    }

    .... 
}
```

Comment: thanks guys, 
I was extending another plugin but was stuck because I was implementing the first part of the code. Implementing the part for extending the plugin totally works :)